# ASP.NET MVC Razor Rendering script javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, helper

I have a question about @helper on Razor. I'm trying do  a @helper simple example, but i can´t obtain a result.I need add custom text to javascript code. On firebug i can see that test var is empty, i don´t understand this. This is the code:

```
@fillString()
@renderScript()

@helper fillString(){
  test  = new List<string>() ;
  test.Add("Id : '1'");
  test.Add("Text: 'hello world'");

}
@helper renderScript(){
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var count = "{ @Html.Raw(test.Count) }";
     var testArray = @{ new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(test.ToArray()); };

 </script>
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I just added semicolon to the end of the longest row and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks Juraj, i saw. But i was not too specific in the trouble. I edit the code in order to see the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is create a JSON object and assign to a javascript variable then you can check this,

```
    @helper renderScript()
      {
        var test = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        test.Add("Id", 1);
        test.Add("Text", "hello world");
        var json = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(test));

        <script type="text/javascript">
           var testObj = @json;
        </script>
    }
```

**Output:**

```
   var testObj = {Id: 1, Text: "hello world"}
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to create a JSON array check this,

```
    var test = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    test.Add("Id", 1);
    test.Add("Text", "hello world");

    var test1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    test1.Add("Id", 2);
    test1.Add("Text", "how are you");

    var json = @Html.Raw(new 
               System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
               .Serialize(new[]{test, test1}));
```

**Output:**

```
   var testArray = [{"Id":1,"Text":"hello world"},{"Id":2,"Text":"how are you"}];
```

Comment: thank you Mark! So the initialization was incorrect. If i wish the following format on array how would be the correct serialization? {array1: {Id: '1',Text: 'hello world'},array2 :{ Id:'2',Text: 'hello world2'}}; Maybe new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,object>> ?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to create an array of JSON objects check the updated answer.